# TypeError in Keras: pass shuffle="batch" even when shuffle="batch" is already provided

Tags: keras, deep-learning, hdf5, tf.keras

I'm trying to train my model using the fit() method with tf.keras, since the input data is from a **hdf5** file, I am passing the parameter **shuffle='batch'** to the **fit()** method. But after the end of the first epoch, the following error shows up:

```py
TypeError: TypeError while preparing batch. If using HDF5 input data, pass shuffle="batch".
```

Here is my fit() method:

```py
model.fit(
    x=features_train,
    y=topics_train,
    batch_size=16384,
    epochs=35,
    callbacks=create_callbacks(),
    validation_data=(features_val, topics_val),
    shuffle='batch'
)
```

The variables `features_train` and `features_val` are taken from a hdf5 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by converting the `features_val` to a numpy array.

```py
features_val_arr = np.array(features_val)

model.fit(
    x=features_train,
    y=topics_train,
    batch_size=16384,
    epochs=35,
    callbacks=create_callbacks(),
    validation_data=(features_val_arr, topics_val),
    shuffle='batch'
)
```